# UFT-8 decoding csv file issues, can't create pandas df

Tags: python, csv, pandas, encoding, utf-8

I apologize if this appears like a duplicate post but I've spent 2 hours searching on stackoverflow and haven't figured out a solution.

I'm loading a csv file into pandas and using a few of the columns for my dataframe. The issue is that one of the columns has a degree symbol in the name °.

If I manually delete ° from the csv, I can load into pandas no problem. However, I will have hundreds of these files to go through so manually deleting doesn't sound like fun.

This is the error I receive:

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 6: invalid start byte"

```
# coding: utf-8
import googlemaps
import folium
import pandas as pd
import re

 df = pd.read_csv('{}{}{}'.format(path, filename, '.csv', encoding='utf-8',errors="ignore")) 
                   .rename(columns={'GPS_x[°]': 'lng', 'GPS_y[°]': 'lat',
                   'ELEVATION_FT[Ft]': 'ele_ft'})
```

I've tried encoding it as latin1/iso-8859-1 with no success. I'm using Pycharm as my IDE and the default file encoding is UTF-8.

I've also tried opening the csv file in notepad++ and encoding it as UTP-8 and saving a new file, still get the same error. I'm not sure what to do

EDIT 1: Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File     "myfile.py", line 18, in <module>
df = pd.read_csv('{}{}{}'.format(path, filename, '.csv', errors="ignore")).rename(columns={'GPS_x[°]': 'lng', 'GPS_y[°]': 'lat', 'ELEVATION_FT[Ft]': 'ele_ft'})

File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 645, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 388, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

 File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 729, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)

File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 922, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1389, in __init__
self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 535, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas\parser.c:6077)

File "pandas\parser.pyx", line 738, in pandas.parser.TextReader._get_header (pandas\parser.c:9215)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Try encoding = 'cp1252'

Comment: Thanks for helping Vaishali. Unfortunately cp1252 doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of typos. You were passing `encoding=` to `format()`, not `read_csv()`, which was subsequently ignored.

`errors` is also erroneous here as it's not supported by `read_csv`.

As your encoding is being reported as `ANSI` by notepad++, you should use `mbcs` as the codec. ANSI means the 8 bit character set of your region, like windows-1252 if you're configured for Western Europe. `mbcs` in Python uses the same region setting to decode/encode.

```
df = pd.read_csv('{}{}{}'.format(path, filename, '.csv'), encoding='mbcs').rename(columns={'GPS_x[°]': 'lng', 'GPS_y[°]': 'lat', 'ELEVATION_FT[Ft]': 'ele_ft'})
```

To make it easier to read, which may have helped you find the problem more quickly, you should do:

```
fq_filename = '{}{}{}'.format(path, filename, '.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(fq_filename, encoding='mbcs')
df = df.rename(columns={'GPS_x[°]': 'lng', 'GPS_y[°]': 'lat', 'ELEVATION_FT[Ft]': 'ele_ft'})
```

Comment: Hi Alistair. I removed the degree characters from a copy of the CSV file in order to continue developing the application. Once I finished writing it, I attempted to import the original csv with the degree chars in tact in order to tackle this problem last.

The IDE was set to UTF-8 and also says the same in the corner below. I also had attempted # coding: utf-8 and latin1 as recommended in other posts.

I've now attempted to use notepad++ to encode the csv into utf-8 and then running the script again. This time it works. Yet I can't manually re-encode each of the csv files so I'm stuck.

Comment: Ah, according to documentation, `errors=` is not a valid argument to `read_csv`. Unaltered, what encoding does notepad++ think your CSV file is?

Comment: it just says ANSI

Comment: Fantastic - that means it's using the current Windows region setting (not utf-8). In your code, get rid of `errors` - it doesn't do anything. Now, set `encoding=mbcs`. This makes Python use the Windows region too. Be warned, this only works on Windows so you'll have to have better solution if you move this code to another platform

Comment: I attempted encoding "mbcs" as well as the aliases listed on the Python 3 docs, ansi/dbcs. Still receiving the same error. I feel like at this point it will be faster to just write a script that removes the ° from every csv. Thanks for trying to help by the way!

Comment: ok, this is good. Is the error still saying `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0` or something else?

Comment: Oh shoot - I've just seen what your problem is. 2 mins

Comment: You are a beautiful person and I think I love you. I spent almost 2 days ripping my hair our, trying to learn about codecs, whereas the entire problem was a stupid syntax mistake where I didn't notice I was passing encoding into format().

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your.csv',encoding ="latin1")
```